# Setting page meta tags with Angular universal dev:ssr works but build:ssr is not working

Tags: angular, seo, server-side-rendering, meta-tags, angular-universal

I am having a challenge with building and serving an Angular Universal application with the express server for good SEO.
When I serve it with the script with command `"dev:ssr": "ng run motif:serve-ssr"` and access it on the browser on the default port `4200` and view the source using the Chrome's view page source option, I can see the correct dynamic meta tags and also the HTML source, which works perfect.

But when I build and serve it with the below commands, the meta tags are not being updated

```
"build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run motif:server:production"

npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr
```

It builds and renders with no errors, but when I view the page source on Chrome I see only the meta tags set for the `index.html` file but I am expecting it to set the tags like the page title, description, image etc for each article data.

I am setting the meta tags in a router data resolver service, and it works fine because I can see its works when running the dev:ssr script.

The CLI version is 9.1.12 (v10 & 11v having issues with ssr and the window object). Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

I'd appreciate any suggestions and solutions to this issue.

Update:

A simplified version of the data resolver is below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { DomSanitizer, TransferState } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { SeoSocialShareData, SeoSocialShareService } from 'ngx-seo';
import { Observable, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ArticleDataResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(
    private seoSocialShareService: SeoSocialShareService,
    private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore,
  ) { }

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    const stateKey = state.url;

    const ref = this.angularFirestore.collection("movementArticles");

    return ref
      .doc(route.params.id)
      .get()
      .pipe(
        map((dataSnap) => {
          const seoData: SeoSocialShareData = {
            title: '...',
            description: '...',
            image: '...',
            author: '...',
            keywords: `...`,
            url: `...`,
            published: '...',
          };

          this.seoSocialShareService.setData(seoData);

          return dataSnap;
        })
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: So no error server side? Can you show simplified code for your resolver?

Comment: Since serve doesn't use the Express Enogine, I assume your Express remove the tags.
Try this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57268938/3852918

Comment: @David I have updated the question to have the resolver sample

Comment: @Remy thank you I will try out the solution in the shared post

Answer (score 1):

I share this service with you
You Can omit the translate service if you do not need translations

and try call the methods in the **constructor** or **ngOnInit** of you component view

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Title, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SEOService {
  constructor(private title: Title, private meta: Meta, private translate: TranslateService) {}

  async getTranslation(word: string) {
    if (word) {
      return await this.translate
        .get(word)
        .toPromise()
        .then(resp => {
          return resp;
        });
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  async updateTitle(title: string) {
    const translation = await this.getTranslation(title);
    this.title.setTitle(translation);
  }

  async updateDescription(desc: string) {
    const translation = await this.getTranslation(desc);
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: translation });
  }

  async updateKeywords(keywords: string) {
    const translation = await this.getTranslation(keywords);
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'keywords', content: translation });
  }

  async updateOgUrl(url: string) {
    const translation = await this.getTranslation(url);
    this.meta.updateTag({
      name: 'og:url',
      property: 'og:url',
      content: translation
    });
  }

  async updateOgTitle(ogTitle: string) {
    const translation = await this.getTranslation(ogTitle);
    this.meta.updateTag({
      name: 'og:title',
      property: 'og:title',
      content: translation
    });
  }

  async updateOgDescription(ogDesc: string) {
    const translation = await this.getTranslation(ogDesc);
    this.meta.updateTag({
      name: 'og:description',
      property: 'og:description',
      content: translation
    });
  }

  async updateOgImage(ogImg: string) {
    const translation = await this.getTranslation(ogImg);
    this.meta.updateTag({
      name: 'og:image',
      property: 'og:image',
      content: translation
    });
  }

  async disableFollow() {
    this.meta.addTag({
      name: 'robots',
      property: 'robots',
      content: 'noindex, nofollow'
    });
  }

  async enableFollow() {
    this.meta.removeTag('robots');
  }
}
```

Example for a global ngOnInit

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Router,
  NavigationEnd,
  ActivatedRoute,
  RouterEvent
} from '@angular/router';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private seoService: SEOService,
  ) {
   
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(() => this.route),
        map(route => {
          while (route.firstChild) {
            route = route.firstChild;
          }
          return route;
        }),
        filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary'),
        mergeMap(route => route.data)
      )
      .subscribe(event => {
        this.seoService.updateTitle(event['title']);
        this.seoService.updateDescription(event['description']);
        this.seoService.updateKeywords(event['keywords']);
        this.seoService.updateOgUrl(event['url']);
        this.seoService.updateOgTitle(event['ogTitle']);
        this.seoService.updateOgDescription(event['ogDesc']);
        this.seoService.updateOgImage(event['ogImage']);
      });
  }
}
```

Hope this can help you ;)